# Mystic Markings on my Washroom Wall!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, cipher

*I found the strangest thing last night. . . . Well, maybe not that strange. . . . I'm not sure. . . .* Anyways, I was in the shower, when I noticed something unusual about the tiles to my left. . . .

Aside from the normal pattern of the tiles on the wall, there was a deep red mark between the tiles, where the grout usually is. It traces an irregular pattern around the tiles, winding this way and that. Occasionally it breaks and starts back up again, a few tiles to the left or right.

At two places there are very thick red dots, but other than that, the line is a set width. I had to take two different pictures, because the lines seem to stop completely for one or two feet.

[image: 1]

Oh, I almost forgot, but on the wall there also was a note written in small scrawled handwriting. It looks like gibberish to me, but who knows, it might be important. I can't add a photo because my camera turns out to be out of space. *How typical. . . .* But instead I'll transcribe the message here:

> *Left, right, all lies in perspective
>
>      Octennial, a pair entwined.*

I'm not a hugely superstitious guy, but it seems very peculiar. *Maybe it holds a certain hidden message?* I'm not too great at this sorta thing, but if I'm being sent a message, I'd sure like to find out what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message says

> **I'm here**

Gotten by

> Starting at the red dot in each picture then following the red line, and interpreting a right turn at a junction as a 1 and a left turn as a 0 we get the binary string:
>
> 1001001 0100111 1101101 1101000 1100101 1110010 1100101
> Which translates to the text above

We know to do this because:

> The clue says: *Octennial a pair entwined*. The idea of a pair suggests binary and seeing as their are 8 bits in a byte it makes us likely that this is what we are looking for. 
> The clue: *Left, right, all lies in perspective* suggests we can derive the binary from the left and right turns